# What is com.coloros.safecenter?

Tags: google-account

I am using Oppo F11 Pro mobile phone. When managing my Google account, under my activities I see "Used com.coloros.safecenter".

What is that?

[image]

Comment: it's a power management taskmanager or something https://dontkillmyapp.com/oppo

Answer (score 1):

This is the security center of your Oppo phone. It's a pre-installed app where you can hide your apps and photos and do much more.